# Increase height, width of docstring in Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, docstring, jupyter-irkernel

When pressing Shift-Tab in Jupyter notebook, it pops-up docstring (help for the function).  How can I change the docstring height/width to minimize scrolling? Currently, the pop-up window is so small and annoying to read through a long documentation. See attached [image: docstring window]picture.

Comment: It is bigger in Jupyter Notebook v7 (alpha). Maybe worth checking out the alpha and providing early feedback to deverlopers?

Comment: @krassowski: Is there no configuration parameter to control this??  It can't be hardcoded...

Comment: Well, it is currently hard-coded. If you would like it to be configurable via setting (which I would support) you can open a feature request on https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues

Comment: @krassowski:  Done! https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/13411  If you need me to add any clarifications, please respond on the github ticket. Cheers!